# Background CSS and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors

I have a problem with my website background. In Firefox and other browsers the background is much whiter and brighter than in Chrome

This is the code for my background :

```
body {background:#ffffff url(../../images/background.jpg); direction:rtl; }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/inK3d.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiqT4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation for this may be that the JPEG image has an embedded color profile that the browsers are interpreting differently. To keep the colors uniform across browsers, the images should be exported with the sRGB color space.

If you're using Photoshop for instance, if you use the "Save for Web & Devices" option, it will automatically convert the image to the sRGB color space. Instructions for changing export color space will change depending on what image editor you are using, of course.

For more information on how color profiles can affect the way colors are displayed on the web, please see [this css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/).